ohmyzsh Agnoster statusline doesn't display correctly in Ubuntu 24.04
People who use ohmyzsh with Agnoster scheme need to install fonts-powerline package for the status line to be displayed correctly. This had been fixing the fonts until Ubuntu 24.04. But it doesn't do the trick in Ubuntu 24.04.
How to fix the Agnoster status line in Ubuntu 24.04?


It looks like the problem is happening only with Ubuntu Sans fonts family with Ubuntu Sans Mono being the default Ubuntu fixed-width font.
The problem can be fixed by changing the system font setting to Ubuntu Mono or any other like Monospace:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 13'
or selecting the font in the terminal preferences:

